# What's the difference between an unregistered HTML Custom Element and a registered HTML Custom Element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, registration, custom-element

If I fail to register a custom element, I note that I can still:

- style the unregistered element using **CSS**
- add events to the unregistered element etc. using **JS**

**Example:**

```js
// REGISTER <my-custom-element-1>
class MyRegisteredCustomElement1 extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
};

customElements.define('my-custom-element-1', MyRegisteredCustomElement1);

// ATTACH EVENT LISTENERS TO BOTH CUSTOM ELEMENTS
const myCustomElement1 = document.getElementsByTagName('my-custom-element-1')[0];
const myCustomElement2 = document.getElementsByTagName('my-custom-element-2')[0];

const customElementAlert = (e) => {

  switch (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase()) {
  
    case ('my-custom-element-1') : console.log('I\'m a registered custom element and I can be scripted and styled.'); break;
    case ('my-custom-element-2') : console.log('I\'m an unregistered custom element. Nevertheless, I can be scripted and styled TOO.'); break;
  }
}

myCustomElement1.addEventListener('click', customElementAlert, false);
myCustomElement2.addEventListener('click', customElementAlert, false);
```

```css
:not(:defined) {
  border: 1px dashed rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

my-custom-element-1,
my-custom-element-2 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  padding: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

my-custom-element-1 {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

my-custom-element-1::after {
  content: 'I\'m a registered custom element.\A CLICK ME';
}

my-custom-element-2 {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}

my-custom-element-2::after {
  content: 'I\'m an unregistered custom element.\A CLICK ME';
}
```

```html
<my-custom-element-1></my-custom-element-1>
<my-custom-element-2></my-custom-element-2>
```

If unregistered custom elements may be styled and scripted, what is it, specifically, that registering a custom element enables?

Comment: *"style the unregistered element using CSS"* Just FWIW, that didn't used to be true in IE9, you had to play games like doing `document.createElement("my-custom-element-2")` once to make it realize that tag was an element. But IE9 is beyond obsolete, and CSS on "unknown" elements worked in IE11 (which is only obsolete, not *beyond* obsolete ;-) ).

Comment: I see you use ``getElementsByTagName`` (oldskool [unless you want the live Nodelist], because ``.querySelector`` is available since IE9 ). To save you some hair-pulling; make a mental note live nodelists do not work in shadowDOM. So you **can NOT do**: ``this.shadowRoot.getElementsByTagName()``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically it associates the element with the class you set for it. It:

- allows using lifecycle callbacks like [`connectedCallback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) (and `disconnectedCallback`)
- allows for custom logic and properties in the constructor.

The `my-custom-element-2` element you've created is just a regular HTML element without the specific class you gave it. If you inspect the DOM you'll see the class of `my-custom-element-2` is `HTMLElement` whereas the class of `my-custom-element-1` is `myRegisteredCustomElement1`.

Comment: This may also help: https://andyogo.github.io/custom-element-reactions-diagram/

Comment: If it's easy to add one (and only if you have time) please can you add to your question a practical example of what can be achieved with a registered custom element on a web page that can't be achieved with an as-yet-unregistered custom element on the same web page. Many thanks.

Comment: @Rounin well, basically "nothing" in terms of capabilities. The important things capabilities wise are shadow DOM and scoped CSS which are possible either way. It's easy to see since there are polyfills for custom elements. However, it's easier to write a `connectedCallback` method like React's componentDidMount (or useEffect) than it is to manually check whenever the element gets attached, debugging is easier because the component class is clearer and so forth.

Comment: Right, that's helpful to have clarified, thanks. So should I just adopt _Custom Element Registration_ as a default best practice every time I deploy a custom element - and give it no more thought other than I should "always register" simply because there's nothing to be lost by always registering?

Comment: Well, it's a lot more convenient to use the hooks (like `connectedCallback`) and JavaScript classes than it is to shim things and manually fire hooks - the mental model is easier. Personally I avoid web components and consider it a lower-level building primitive and favour frameworks like Vue and React that are _way_ more common in practice. I just have a lot of experience because I work in a testing company (Testim) where we have a bunch of clients that use custom elements and shadow DOM including some (like Salesforce) that implement it themselves.

Comment: Rephrase _" simply because there's nothing to be lost by always registering"_ to _"simply because there is so much gained when registering"_

Comment: And do not call it an _**"Unregistered Custom Element"**_, that implies it has a relation to Custom Elements, it has not. Only when you use the Custom Elements **API** it becomes a Custom Element. You don't call an Array that you **did not** pass to Set an "Unregistered Set" either. Or a pile of bricks an "unbuilt house"

Comment: Correct, spec wise: "An element’s custom element state is one of "undefined", "failed", "uncustomized", "precustomized", or "custom". An element whose custom element state is "uncustomized" or "custom" is said to be defined. An element whose custom element state is "custom" is said to be custom." - the custom element state is set by `define`ing the element.

Comment: Re: _"Only when you use the Custom Elements **API** it becomes a Custom Element"_ Thank you, @Danny'365CSI'Engelman - that's really well articulated.